# How to drag/drop both file and text in same window in wxWidgets?

Tags: c++, file, text, drag-and-drop, wxwidgets

I'm working on a program that needs to open images from both local disk and internet. WxWidgets provides `wxFileDropTarget` and `wxTextDropTarget`, but each class can only support one type of data object (`wxFileDataObject` and `wxTextDataObject`). I've try to derive class from two base classes, but the compiler says `ambiguous conversions from 'CMyDropTarget *' to 'wxDropTarget *'`. How can I create a window accept two data type?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow, it would be easier to help with this question if you included the actual code that causes the error. Also, surround inline code with backticks to make it stand out. (e.g. `wxFileDropTarget`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, the simplest solution is to use a `wxDataObjectComposite`, to which you `Add()` both a `wxFileDataObject` and a `wxTextDataObject`.

You derive your own class from `wxDropTarget`, override its pure virtual `OnData()`, and call its `SetDataObject()` with the appropriately constructed `wxDataObjectComposite` in your derived class' constructor.

There's a pretty good example of it all in the docs for [`wxDataObjectComposite`](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/3.0/classwx_data_object_composite.html). It gives you an overview of what needs to be done, just keep in mind that there are a few details that I think are not quite right in there:

- The call to `wxDropTarget::OnData()` won't work, as that's a pure virtual (you shouldn't call it at all in my opinion).
- You should, however, call `GetData()` instead, to populate the `wxDataObjectComposite` with the preferred data format (or another one that is available), and test its return value.
- `dataObjects->GetReceivedFormat()` should be `dataobjComp->GetReceivedFormat()`.

Comment: Thanks a lot! 'wxDataObjectComposite' is what I need and works. The three details are also accurate. I've overlooked this class before and tried various classes derived from 'wxDataObjectSimple'. Below is my final code.
'

Comment: Sorry, comment time expired and I don't know how to post long code in comment. Thanks again!